# Why ActionDispatch::Static is removed from the middleware stack in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleware

I am trying to understand how rails serves static files under **/public**, and if I get it correctly, the `ActionDispatch::Static` middleware is responsible for this.

However, I noticed that it's only available in development environment:

```
$ rake middleware

use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
.
.
```

and in production:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake middleware

use Rack::Sendfile
use Rack::Lock
.
.
```

How are static files served in production then? My guess is that this is handled by the web server itself (apache, puma...etc) to improve performace, is this correct?

And if that's the case, then why create a dedicated middleware for this task in development?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, nowadays hardly anyone uses rails app to serve static assets. That would be a horrible waste of processing power. They're either handled by frontend (nginx or the like) or pushed to CDN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is controlled by a setting in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_files = false
```

The reason that this is not enabled in development, is because on development you don't need the extra functionality/overhead of nginx or apache. For example, you don't want your browser to get instructions to cache these files while developing.

`ActionDispatch::Static` will just load these files from disk and send them to the browser, nothing fancy. All request to `public` will be handled by `ActionDispatch::Static`, all other requests are handled by your Rails application.

Comment: Note that this configuration has been renamed to: `config.public_file_server.enabled`